# How to plot graph of perpendicularly polarized uniform plane wave is incident obliquely on a dielectric to conductor boundary using Matlab

Tags: matlab, electromagnetic, wave

I am writing the code for the equation which is attached below (
[image of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3YtP.jpg)).
I have written the code but getting errors. I want to plot the graph of E and H as underlined in the image.

In the code i have written the code for electric field (electricField).
So can i improve the code and plot it as i want.

```
theta=0:0.05:2*pi;
f=100;
omega=2*pi*f;
Emax=11;
Bmax=11;
lambda=4000;
k=(2*pi)/lambda;


%phase_vel=omega/k*sin(theta);
%plot(theta,phase_vel);

%wavelength=lambda\sin(theta);
%plot(theta,wavelength);

beta=k;
Ei=100;
z=0:1:100;
%electricField=2j*Ei*sin(beta*z*cos(theta)).*sin(beta*x*sin(theta));
electricField=2*Ei*sin(beta.*z.*cos(theta)).*exp(-1.*beta.*x.*sin(theta));
%z=0:1:100;
%yline=animatedline('lineWidth',1,'Color','r');
zline=animatedline('lineWidth',1,'Color','b');
xline=animatedline('lineWidth',1,'Color','g');

axis([0 2*pi -11 11 0 2*pi]);
view(45,20);   

title("Electromagnetic wave");
xlabel('Propogation direction(x)');
ylabel('electric Field(Y)');
zlabel('magnetic Field(Z)');

hold on;

for i=1:length(theta)
    addpoints(xline,electricField(i),0,0);
    
    addpoints(zline,theta(i),0,electricField(i));
    drawnow
    pause(0.02);
    hold on;
end




ERROR
Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the
second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'.

Error in xzfdsgs (line 22)
electricField=2*Ei*sin(beta*z*cos(theta)).*sin(beta*x*sin(theta));
```

even after replacing '*' with '.*' i am getting error
"
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in xzfdsgs (line 22)
electricField=2*Ei*sin(beta.*z.*cos(theta)).*exp(-1.*beta.*x.*sin(theta));

"

Comment: We are NOT a homework service.  Homework with no effort at a solution is locked.  We will help you overcome misconceptions, but you will learn nothing if we do the work for you.  Edit your question putting down what you know, what you have tried and where you do not understand.

Comment: Clearly, your electric field computation is wrong. The ranges from `theta` and `z` do not match. How are you expecting the multiplication to work if you have functions of different sizes? Most importantly, you are not showing any minimal effort in what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Melendrez, I am new to MatLab maybe I am wrong that's why I am asking small doubt.

Answer (score 0):

My advice: Start with 2*Ei and then add each element of the equation one by one. That way you know exactly which part is giving you an error and we can help/you can debug it from there.

(Yes, this is more of a comment than an answer but I'm just shy of 50 rep, so)